# How to deploy a docker image from docker hub to ibm cloud free tier

Tags: docker, deployment, openshift, ibm-cloud

I am kind of new here. I would like to know to deploy my docker image from the docker hub to IBM cloud-free tier using IBM cloud standalone CLI. I was using the Openshift online starter plan, where with just about 4 commands the image can be deployed. Can someone list me how its done or point me to a resource that shows how it's done.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So if you can explain more about your free-tier, I can edit my response later. For now, I will explain for both options. You can find free services from [here](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/free). You will need IBM Cloud Cli tool which can be downloaded:

- [With ibmcloud cli, helm, kubectl, docker and more](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-getting-started)
- [Only standalone ibmcloud cli](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-install-ibmcloud-cli)

First account type is: **The lite account**. In this option, you cannot create IBM Kubernetes service or OpenShift cluster. You can only access to some lite services (apprx. 40 services) and one of them is Cloud Foundry Public. IBM Cloud let you use 256 MB of RAM on Cloud Foundry Public with free of charge. You can use the following command:

```sh
ibmcloud cf push \
  --docker-image <your-image> \
  --docker-username <your-username> \
  --random-route \
  -i 1 \
  -m <memory_limit_max_256_mb>
```

You can find more details by writing `ibmcloud cf push --help`

---

Second account type is: **trial/free-tier account** which can be had by two ways: a feature code or switching to pay-as-you-go.

This option includes the Cloud Foundry Public also, I won't repeat it. But with this account type, you will have IBM Kubernetes Service Free (Deletes itself 30 days later, you can create one more after that time)

When you create a kubernetes cluster on IBM Cloud, you will see the service page. There is an `access` menu on left tab-menu. You have to follow those steps to be able to access to your kubernetes cluster from your workspace.

Then it is easy to deploy your image by entering:

`kubectl create deployment app --image=<your_image_url>`

If your image is not publicly accessible, then you have to create an imagepullsecret and bind it to your service account but this is out-of-topic. [You can find it in here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)

Comment: I tried using the above command but I  am getting an error even though I have not deployed the image anywhere else.

Comment: Invoking 'cf push ---doker-image kaviin27/vcloan:v2 --random-route -i 1 -m 100M'...

Pushing app ---doker-image to org kavin-dsc / space models as kaviin27@gmail.com...
Getting app info...
open C:\Users\kavin\AppData\Local\Comms\UnistoreDB\USS.jtx: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: So, this can a local dev environment configuration problem. Let's try it in cloud. Open your IBM Cloud, click to **cloud shell** button on top left. Try to use `ibmcloud cf push ...` command in there. (You may have to run `ibmcloud target --cf` before push command) @KavinSrinaathVK

Answer (score 0):

For free tier clusters (kubernetes only, no OCP) you'll need to do this in the web console.

Answer (score 0):

> OpenShift worker nodes are available for paid accounts and standard
> clusters only. You can create OpenShift clusters that run version 4.3
> or 3.11 (deprecated). The operating system is Red Hat Enterprise Linux
> 7.

Following the instructions in this [tutorial](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openshift?topic=openshift-openshift_tutorial) to create a standard Red Hat OpenShift on IBM Cloud cluster, open the OpenShift console, access built-in OpenShift components, deploy an app in an OpenShift project, and expose the app on an OpenShift route so that external users can access the service.

To create an application from a container image in DockerHub, you just have to run the below command with the image name

```
oc new-app mysql
```

For other strategies to build the container image, check the [documentation here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/applications/application_life_cycle_management/creating-applications-using-cli.html#dockerhub-mysql-image)

Answer (score 0):

There is a new option to deploy Docker images to IBM Cloud.
The new option is called IBM Cloud Code Engine and is currently in Beta and available in the us-south region.

Login to IBM Cloud:

`ibmcloud login` or if you are authenticated in your browser try `ibmcloud login --sso`

Target the us-south region and an existing resource group:

`ibmcloud target -r us-south -g default`

Install the Code Engine plugin into your ibmcloud cli:
`ibmcloud plugin install code-engine`

Create a Code Engine project:

`ibmcloud code-engine project create --name myProject`

Create a Code Engine application from a docker image:

`ibmcloud code-engine application create --name myapp --image docker.io/ibmcom/helloworld`

Wait until it's deployed.

Comment: thanks, does this work for the free tier (IBM Lite account)? I see the below error when trying to create the project.                                                                                                                          ibmcloud code-engine project create --name vcloan
Creating project 'vcloan'...
FAILED
Cannot select project 'vcloan'.

Internal error:
Your resource group quota does not allow the use of non-lite plans.